# Error with install of ruby on rails in server(vps) ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, linux, ubuntu-16.04

Good day, today I installed ruby on rails on my server, nevertheless there are errors in execution of my app:

```
rails new testingApp
cd testingApp
rails server

// Appears in my console(Putty) a error.
```

The error is:

```
Could not find gem 'puma (~> 3.7)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I do not understand reason of error and I need help regarding this.

I learned to installing Ruby and complements from youtube:
https://youtu.be/ml_-nWq0LEg

The command used for installing there are:

```
Ruby installation: sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev libsqlite3-dev

Rails installation: sudo gem install rails –v 5.0.0.1

NodeJS installation: sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

My server have technical requirements:

- Ubuntu 16.04.
- 256 mb of ram.
- 0.5 Core.

Sorry for my english is very bad.

Thanks for reading of my post and help.
[image: This is error in my console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you project created after putting the command

```
rails new testingApp
```

then it is ok but need to install all dependencies

```
cd testingApp
#=> then run bundler
bundle install
#=> if bundle run properly then run
rails server or rails s
```

Hope will work

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the gem sources listed in Gemfile.

```
$ cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Please run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to install these gems.
and run `bundle exec rails server` to start rails on those dependencies.